# Dynamically generate JSON in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I have terraform code that looks something like this:

```
locals {
  overrides = {
    foo = {
      connections = {
        connection-one = {
          bool_setting = "true"
        }
        connection-two = {
          string_value = "primary"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  my_json = {
    "description" = "blah"
    "psk" = {
      for_each = try(local.overrides.foo.connections, {}) # <-- problem
      each.key : random_string.password[each.key]
    }
  }
}

resource "random_string" "password" {
  for_each = try(local.overrides.foo.connections, {})
  length   = 20
  special  = true
}

output "json_output" {
  value = jsonencode(local.my_json)
}
```

I know that my code is wrong because `for_each` blocks are not allowed where I have pointed out the problem, but my hope is that this snippet would demonstrate what I am trying to achieve.

NB: `local.overrides` may not always have the `connections` attribute, hence the `try()`.

I would like an output that looks like below:

```
{
  "description": "blah",
  "psk": {
    "connection-one": "g2rL6IEF1XXp_JL]N<H!",
    "connection-two": "EVBQvSj@5a9lo:OZ<S_T"
   }
}
```

How do I achieve this in Terraform?

Comment: What is the current JSON format string with your config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for_each` argument in `resource`, `data`, and `dynamic "..."` blocks is an intrinsic part of those particular language features and is not an independent unit that you can use in isolation in other parts of your configuration.

However, if you need to generate a new sequence or mapping value from an existing collection in a location that expects an expression then you can use a [`for` expression](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for), which are designed for that specific purpose.

To produce a mapping from instances of `random_string.password` to just the generated password (without the other parts of each object) then you could write an expression like this:

```
{
  for k, obj in random_string.password :
  k => obj.result
}
```

This expression relies on the fact that `random_string.password` materializes as a map from instance keys to objects representing each of the instances of that resource. [The documentation for `random_string`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/random/latest/docs/resources/string) says that instances of that type have an attribute `result` containing the generated string, and so `obj.result` in this expression sets the value of each element of the result to the value of the `result` attribute of the corresponding resource instance.

Here's how you can integrate that into your `local.my_json` definition:

```
locals {
  my_json = {
    "description" = "blah"
    "psk" = {
      for k, obj in random_string.password :
      k => obj.result
    }
  }
}
```

---

Incidentally:

If these strings you are generating really are passwords then it may be more appropriate to use [`random_password`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/random/latest/docs/resources/password) instead, which has a similar set of capabilities and arguments.

Along with just being a better description of the intent of the resource, the provider also declares the result of that resource type as being "sensitive" so Terraform won't show the generated passwords in the UI by default, but will still save them in the state so you can retrieve them using commands like `terraform output -raw json_output` when needed.

Comment: The `for` loop should be used against the map, not against the random_string (or random_password) resource. Keys from the map become keys in the JSON file, and the password associated with the key (from the password's for_each indexing) becomes the value in the JSON. See the example shown in the question to understand what is desired

Comment: Disregard my earlier comment. This has actually worked. Thank you!